# Cannot install code deploy Agent on ubuntu 18

Tags: amazon-web-services, pipeline

My EC2 ubuntu server already had code-deploy agent and few days ago it didn't work.Then i uninstall completely agent and tried to reinstall it using previous install file.( first time i install agent from that file successfully.)
When i tried to install agent i got that error now.

```
./install auto

I, [2023-04-27T08:15:53.105798 #5293]  INFO -- : Starting Ruby version check.
I, [2023-04-27T08:15:53.105961 #5293]  INFO -- : Starting update check.
I, [2023-04-27T08:15:53.106019 #5293]  INFO -- : Attempting to automatically detect supported package manager type for system...
I, [2023-04-27T08:15:53.113675 #5293]  INFO -- : Checking AWS_REGION environment variable for region information...
I, [2023-04-27T08:15:53.113863 #5293]  INFO -- : Checking EC2 metadata service for region information...
I, [2023-04-27T08:15:53.131950 #5293]  INFO -- : Downloading version file from bucket aws-codedeploy-us-east-1 and key latest/LATEST_VERSION...
dpkg-query: package 'codedeploy-agent' is not installed and no information is available
Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files,
and dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list their contents.
I, [2023-04-27T08:15:53.183052 #5293]  INFO -- : Running version No running version
I, [2023-04-27T08:15:53.183424 #5293]  INFO -- : Downloading package from bucket aws-codedeploy-us-east-1 and key releases/codedeploy-agent_1.6.0-49_all.deb...
I, [2023-04-27T08:15:53.234281 #5293]  INFO -- : Executing `/usr/bin/gdebi -n -o Dpkg::Options::=--force-confdef -o Dkpg::Options::=--force-confold /tmp/codedeploy-agent_1.6.0-49_all.tmp-20230427-5293-9z1ck5.deb`...
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
Reading state information... Done
This package is uninstallable
Failed to satisfy all dependencies (broken cache)
E, [2023-04-27T08:15:55.264380 #5293] ERROR -- : Error installing /tmp/codedeploy-agent_1.6.0-49_all.tmp-20230427-5293-9z1ck5.deb.
```

Now systemctl output is this.

```
● codedeploy-agent.service
   Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2023-04-10 07:13:46 UTC; 2 weeks 3 days ago

Apr 10 07:13:46 ip-172-31-2-29 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: AWS CodeDeploy Host Agent...
Apr 10 07:13:46 ip-172-31-2-29 systemd[1]: codedeploy-agent.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=203
Apr 10 07:13:46 ip-172-31-2-29 systemd[1]: codedeploy-agent.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Apr 10 07:13:46 ip-172-31-2-29 systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: AWS CodeDeploy Host Agent.
```

No any systemd file or initd file has been created for service.

When i tried to uninstall the agent it says this.

```
sudo dpkg --purge codedeploy-agent

dpkg: warning: ignoring request to remove codedeploy-agent which isn't installed
```

also checked code-deploy agent logs and last log file containing these output.

```
2023-04-07 17:31:16 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(29553)]: Version file found in /opt/codedeploy-agent/.version with agent version OFFICIAL_1.0-1.1597_deb.
2023-04-07 17:32:01 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(29553)]: [Aws::CodeDeployCommand::Client 200 45.218835 0 retries] poll_host_command(host_identifier:"arn:aws:ec2:us-east-3:xxxxxxx:instance/i-xxxxxxx")  

2023-04-07 17:32:02 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(29553)]: Version file found in /opt/codedeploy-agent/.version with agent version OFFICIAL_1.0-1.1597_deb.
2023-04-07 17:32:47 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(29553)]: [Aws::CodeDeployCommand::Client 200 45.037227 0 retries] poll_host_command(host_identifier:"arn:aws:ec2:us-east-3:xxxxxxxx:instance/i-xxxxx")  

2023-04-07 17:32:48 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(29553)]: Version file found in /opt/codedeploy-agent/.version with agent version OFFICIAL_1.0-1.1597_deb.
2023-04-07 17:33:02 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(3963)]: Checking first if any deployment lifecycle event is in progress master 29549
2023-04-07 17:33:02 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(3963)]: Stopping master 29549
2023-04-07 17:33:02 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(29549)]: master 29549: Received TERM - stopping children and shutting down
2023-04-07 17:33:02 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(29553)]: InstanceAgent::Plugins::CodeDeployPlugin::CommandPoller of master 29549: Received TERM - setting internal shutting down flag and possibly finishing last run
2023-04-07 17:33:02 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(29553)]: InstanceAgent::Plugins::CodeDeployPlugin::CommandPoller: Gracefully shutting down agent child threads now, will wait up to 7200 seconds
2023-04-07 17:33:02 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(29553)]: InstanceAgent::Plugins::CodeDeployPlugin::CommandPoller: All agent child threads have been shut down
2023-04-07 17:33:02 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(29553)]: agent exiting now
2023-04-07 17:33:33 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(29553)]: [Aws::CodeDeployCommand::Client 200 45.280445 0 retries] poll_host_command(host_identifier:"arn:aws:ec2:us-east-3:xxxxxxxxxx:instance/i-xxxxxxxxx")
```

I need to reinstall codedeploy agent into this server without creating new EC2. How can i do it?

Comment: You didn't share the commands you used to uninstall the agent and how you are trying to re-install it again

Comment: Thank you for quick response. i updated the question. and also i use the this command to install agent. "./install auto" (I already had install sh file which i previously used to install agent) | and uninstall command is this. "sudo dpkg --purge codedeploy-agent"

Comment: This is already aws documentation have. in my question i mentioned i tried it and got errors from those steps.

Comment: After executing this command issue has been resolved. "apt --fix-broken install". Thank you very much for the support.

Answer (score 0):

1. apt --fix-broken install
2. sudo apt install ruby-full

issue fixed using above --fix-broken command.